# system freeze after monitor power save

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a DELL U2414H connected via the Display Port as a secondary display. When the monitor goes to power save mode and I try to wake it up, I get the following symptoms:

```
* The primary display wakes up and displays the background screen with an Ubuntu logo
* The secondary display stays black
* Entering my password to unlock screen achieves nothing
* Trying CTRL-ALT-F1 (etc.) achieves nothing
* Only reboot helps
```

The phenomenon occurred after changing the secondary display, the previous secondary display, a Fujitsu monitor connected via VGA , didn't have problems in this respect.

I can mitigate the problem by switching the secondary screen off when I intend to have a break from screen work. This pushes the windows to the primary screen and when I resume screen wrok I can pull them onto the secondary screen again. Unfortunately, this mitigation fails in the case of unintended breaks.

I did some googling and searching, but I found no solutions to my problem. I got the error messages in the file .xsession.errors:

```
openConnection: connect: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
cannot connect to brltty at :0
Skript für ibus unter run_im gestartet.
Skript für auto unter run_im gestartet.
Skript für default unter run_im gestartet.
```

What can I do to avoid this unwanted behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel has a open source driver, you can download with the following link.

https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb

go to the download location and run

> sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

> sudo dpkg -i intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb

Type intel in your launcher and you will find intel graphics installer for linux,

CLick on it and follow through the instructions.

Reboot.

I hope this will help.

2. Other workaround that i use since i am on ubuntu 14.10 is keeping the system awake  to stop power save mode.

I do by changing the  "turn screen off when inactive" option in

> System settings --> Power --> Turn screen off when inactive
>   Change it to "Never"

I hope this helps :D

Comment: The change in the system settings works for me, I didn't try the Intel driver.

Comment: Sigh, it works only partially. After a longer break (about 1 hour) I found myself locked out again.